# why `int**` can't be casted to `const int**`

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am new to C++, but I met an issue:

```
const int* pp2;
int p2;
pp2 = &p2;
```

this is right, but the same rule for this code:

```
const int** pp2;
int* p2;
pp2 = &p2;
```

this is an error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int**’ to ‘const int**’ [-fpermissive]
```

I am confused.
`int*` can be casted to `const int*`, but why `int**` can't be casted `const int**`?